# How do I group posts from wp query by 3, while also separating each post in its own div?

Tags: php, wordpress

Sorry, it was hard to word this question. Below is the end result HTML I am trying to achieve with a WP Query. It's for a carousel that has 3 posts per slide.

```
<div id="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-slide">
        <div class="wp-post">Post 1</div>
        <div class="wp-post">Post 2</div>
        <div class="wp-post">Post 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-slide">
        <div class="wp-post">Post 4</div>
        <div class="wp-post">Post 5</div>
        <div class="wp-post">Post 6</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Basically, I need a way to have each individual post wrapped with a "wp-post" div, but every three posts wrapped in a "carousel-slide" div within a WP query of all posts. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="carousel">
<?php
  $args = array('post_type' => 'page',
                 'posts_per_page'=> -1
             );
             
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) 
{
    $i = 1;
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) 
    {
        $the_query->the_post();
    ?>
<?php if($i == 1){ ?>
    <div class="carousel-slide">
<?php } ?>
    <div class="wp-post"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></div>
 <?php if($i == 3) { ?>
 </div>
<?php $i = 1;}else{$i++;} ?>

<?php }
} ?>
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much! It was driving me crazy haha